# Several dataframes should have the same index values. How to compare?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy, scikits

I have several dataframes. All are time series indexed.
The problem is, some have missing data and I need to check which ones have differing date indexes.
Now all contain about the same values, there's just the case where one or two have an additional value or are missing a few, in which case I need to make a call to a different data provider to get these values for the rest of the dataframes so the algorithms don't break.

```
INDEX    VAL

DF1
01-01-17 6.00
03-01-17 4.53
05-01-17 8.91

DF2
01-01-17 4.11
03-01-17 8.67
07-01-17 1.93
09-01-17 3.11

DF3
01-01-17 4.00
03-01-17 20.10
07-01-17 3.12

DF4
01-01-17 8.11
03-01-17 1.89
06-01-17 3.89
07-01-17 4.89
```

There's hundreds of values and it's hard to go through by hand.

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to compare them or create a kind of matrix which shows me what values I need to obtain for each df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this using
list comprehension

- list comprehension
- `pd.concat`
- `reindex`
- `eval`
- dataframe style for highlights

:

```
list_of_df = ['df1','df2','df3','df4']
concat_df = pd.concat([eval(i) for i in list_of_df])
pd.concat([eval(i).reindex(pd.date_range(concat_df.index.min(), 
                                         concat_df.index.max(), 
                                         freq='MS'))
                  .rename(columns={1:i}) for i in ['df1','df2','df3','df4']], axis=1)\
  .style.applymap(lambda x: 'background: yellow' if pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full code you used, including what method you were using to put them into a df?

Comment: @Harryw, I am using pd.read_clipboad(), where i can highlight text from your question and execute df1 = pd.read_clipboard() and it will create that dataframe. `df1 = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=True,header=None,index_col = 0)` in particluar.

Comment: @Harryw I am using Jupyter Notebook for my coding and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) look at [dataframe.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). This will ensure that you have the same index values in each dataframe; any missing rows will be set to nan.

2) use [dataframe.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to combine the dataframes. With the how keyword you can specify the type of merging. In your case, 'outer' may be the right choice if you don't have a "master index". There is a good [description of merge, join, and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) available.